# What are the good tools that can be use for performance testing on a website?

Tags: testing, performance-testing

I am looking for an open-source tool or any tool that can be use for performance testing on a website. Any suggestion will do.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of assumptions which will have to be made here in order to provide a response.  You can also make the argument that your question could be applying to multiple conditions: Single user performance, Multiple user performance, platform specific performance (such as mobile).

I am going to suggest a framework for how you might evaluate tools.   Start with your analysis, what you expect to get out of the tool (or tools).  What type of analysis and reporting capabilities do you need for reporting to your engineering and business stakeholders.

[image]

In general, for performance work, single, multiple or platform specific, you will want a tool that can collect the information needed to understand your response time. Response time is governed by how the system uses resources.   You can observe from the widget that there are specific questions you will want your tool to address.

This implies some items.  Not only must your tool be able to exercise your application in your technical environment (linux, Windows, Mac, Plan9, BeOS, Android, iPhone, ....), but you need the ability to monitor the system under test for the collection of resources.  This is both at the OS, The guest OS (.Net/Java VM, RDMS, ...) and service level.  Then, at the end of the test you will need to be able to bring the timing records and the resource monitors together on a common timestamp to examine what resources are in play at the time the timing records ran long.  Being able to report out your findings to your business and engineering stakeholders with minimal overhead is a strong plus.

You will also want to take a very hard look at the skills of you or your team.   If the best tool on the market uses Ferengi9 as a development language and requires an HP SuperMini to run it, and your organization lacks the language skills and the supermini, well, you're going to be out of luck.   Even if you had the supermini and your team was clueless on the scripting language you are going to be out of luck.  This is true independent of the license model of the tool.

Analysis is where the value is added in the performance testing process.  The building of tests and execution is all about the collection of data.   There are many tools in the market which simply stop at the collection.  Heck, there are substantial groups of tools which stop at the collection of timing records, leaving monitoring, analysis and reporting to some other tool to plug into.

As you examine your tool options, keep these tool classes in mind

- Full featured tools.  These tools allow for the production of load, the collection of timing records and monitor data, analysis and reporting.
- Limited Feature Tools.  These tools allow for the production of load, the collection of timing records and some monitoring data.  Extremely limited analysis or reporting - it is assumed other tools will be used
- Load Throwers.  These tools allow for the production of load, the collection of timing records.  Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting are left to additional tools.
- Denial of Services tools.  These tools allow for production of large point loads. Rarely is response time data provided.  All Monitoring, analysis and reporting are left to other tools.

Most (but not all) commercial multi-user performance testing tools fall into the full featured tool set.  As you move further down the stack you get more open source tools, until you arrive at something like "Bees with Machine Guns" at the bottom

I know you started your question with a desire for a recommendation.  But, not knowing your development OS, your monitoring needs, your analysis and reporting needs, your (or your team's) foundation skills in languages and testing it would be almost impossible to provide a high value recommendation, **Go with Tool X - It is strong like Mule and will never fail you**

Hopefully this provides a framework where you can examine tools that you have found using your foundation research skills on your favorite search engine to understand the capabilities of the tool you are looking at, whether it will work for your technical and business needs, whether you will need to pair a tool with other tools for a complete solution, & whether it will work at all in your environment with your intended users to allow you to delivery valuable insight into the performance of your application under test.